# Small UPS for bluetooth audio device

Tags: usb, basic, decoupling-capacitor

I've got a bluetooth audio receiver in my car and am finding it annoying that it turns off immediately after the ignition is turned off.  For example if we're stopped for a while I prefer to turn the engine off, but this will stop any music.  I am thinking of putting a decoupling super-cap in parallel with the USB device (an iClever Himbox HB01).

Would that generally work, any issues to worry about?

Not sure how much current the device actually draws, but datasheets from similar looking chips suggest about 30mA, so a 5F cap should give me about 10 minutes—presuming I'm understand what I'm calculating.

These larger caps seem to be quite expensive, I've found an Eaton PHV-5R4V505-R for £7 so was wondering whether other alternatives would be cheaper and not too complicated?

Comment: It would probably be cheaper to buy a BT receiver with a built-in battery.

Comment: A small sealed lead acid battery will have much better energy density (per volume and price) than these caps.

Comment: A delayed turn off car relay module would work better. It connects the circuit via the always on power, and doesn't disconnected it until a few minutes after the switched power is turned off.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Yes, I had one before this one, but it kept turning itself off when USB power went on/off.

Comment: I trade you with mine if you weren't so far away...

Comment: @Passerby: that sounds the best, not sure why that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put a USB battery in between the device and the USB port?

Just make sure you get one that supports "pass-though" like this $10 one..

[https://www.amazon.com/Patriot-Ultra-Compact-Rechargeable-Warranty-Smartphone/dp/B00DW9PUD8/ref=as_sl_pc_ss_til?tag=joshcom-20&linkCode=w01&linkId=S5RBTYAWFPEL3FXT&creativeASIN=B00DW9PUD8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DW9PUD8)

"Pass-though" means you can have the battery connected to both the power supply and the device at the same time and it will "pass-though" the power. Once the power supply is removed (car turned off), then the battery will kick in and supply to the device.